# Validating commands before execution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, inversion-of-control, command-pattern

In the system I'm currently building, I use the command pattern to carry out all operations possible. I have chosen the CommandMessage and CommandHandler approach, separating logic from data.
This works fine for now, but I've run into a problem - validation.

How do I actually validate whether a command can execute or not?

Right now I have a `CanExecute(ICommandExecutionContext context)` on every command, making it responsible for determining whether or not it can execute. A `ICommandExecutionContext` is then typechecked in each command, to see if it's of the correct context type, and afterwards if the information makes the command executable in that context.

Everything is wrapped in a `ICommandService` that can validate and execute commands, based on their names, context and message. Besides that, it also publishes events about command execution, and perform permission checks.

The problem originates from the UI (an ASP.NET MVC 3 application). I would like to only show valid commands in each view, but I have failed to come up with a solution I really like. Currently my controller asks the command service, whether a command can execute, given a concrete context like so:

```
var executionContext = new SystemCommandExecutionContext("SignInCommand", CurrentPrincial);
var canExecute = _commandService.CanExecute(executionContext);
/* Handle the result to enable or disable the action link */
```

For other types of commands, that works on concrete domain objects, I use the same command service method, but a different context, where I pass the domain object id, like this:

```
[HttpPost, Authorize, ValidateAntiForgeryToken /* etc. */]
public ActionResult Delete(Guid id)
{
    /* Note the additional object id in the context */
    var executionContext = new EntityCommandExecutionContext("DeletePersonCommand", CurrentPrincipal, id);
    var canExecute = _commandService.CanExecute(executionContext);

    if(canExecute)
    {
        var message = new DeletePersonCommandMessage(id);
        var isValid = _commandService.IsValid(executionContext, message);
        if(isValid)
        {
            var result = _commandService.Execute(executionContext, message);
            /* More logic here... Not very DRY :( */
        }            
    }
}
```

I guess the above is okay for now, though not very DRY.
But what I would like to accomplish is to disable the action links, based on the result from CanExecute.

How can I do that?

I've decided to "hardcode" all command links on each view, so I don't have to pass a collection of command names etc. - that path is too difficult (unless someone has a clever idea ;)

My current stack consist of NHibernate, Castle Windsor, ASP.NET MVC 3, AutoMapper.

Answer (score 1):

As small note, your command objects are those which are serialized and sent to a (possibly remote) service to be handled by a command handler then this is not an instance of the command pattern in the GoF sense, because the command object itself does not provide an execution method. The purpose of the command message object in this case is to **represent** an action together with the required parameters. Some sources call it a serializable method call. Message objects should not contain behavior, only data, and a command message is no exception. This means that the process of determining whether a given command can be executed in a particular context should be handled by a separate service. The specific implementation of this validation service depends on the criteria that are used in determining whether a given command can execute. It may be able to validate a command based on some context and the type of the command:

```
interface ICommandValidationService
{
  bool CanExecute(object context, Type commandType);
}
```

The context object should be independent of the actual command being executed. Instead it should contain more global contextual values such as the user, user permissions, etc. The ability of a command to execute would be decided using this context.

Disabling or hiding action links based on the execution status of a command can be implemented using a view model like this:

```
class ActionLinkViewModel
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

Where the enabled value is assigned in the controller by the `ICommandValidationService`. Furthermore, you can extend the [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) to specify whether a given site map node is visible.

Comment: This is about the same thing I have right now. I'm not sure what you mean regarding my command pattern implementation. Could you elaborate on that? I believe (maybe I wasn't clear), you forgot about commands operating on domain objects? I'm not sure how I can provide a context with domain information to the validation service?